# Test new data in NARX network MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series

I have trained the NARX net in MATLAB with below code.I want to test the trained network from new inputs (testX) and targets (testY).But i am getting error in last line forecastLoad = sim(net, testX')';

```
 X = tonndata(trainX,false,false);
 T = tonndata(trainY,false,false);

 inputSeries = X;

 targetSeries = T;

% Create a Nonlinear Autoregressive Network with External Input
 inputDelays = 1:3;
feedbackDelays = 1:3;
hiddenLayerSize = 20;
net = narxnet(inputDelays,feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize);

% Prepare the Data for Training and Simulation
% The function PREPARETS prepares time series data 

[inputs,inputStates,layerStates,targets] = ... 
    preparets(net,inputSeries,{},targetSeries);

% Set up Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets,inputStates,layerStates);
%% 

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs,inputStates,layerStates);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
MAE = mae(errors);


 %Test on new data
  forecastLoad = sim(net, testX')';
  error = testY-forecastLoad;
```

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: it says (https://pasteboard.co/GK97WMv.jpg)

Comment: looks like `inputs` you used for training and `testX'` has different dimensions. Check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the line Matlab test the data:

```
% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs,inputStates,layerStates);
```

Why do not you enter the data in the same way? Lets do this:

```
% Prepare first the data.

[inputs,inputStates,layerStates,targets] = ... 
     preparets(net,textX,{},testY);
% And then predict.
forecastLoad = net(inputs,inputStates,layerStates);
```

Comment: `net` is already used previously, so we should use the same or different like `netc ` for new data testing?

Comment: The same net, of course. Because the net is trained with the 'inputSeries'. The line which changes the network's weights is 

`[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets,inputStates,layerStates);`

But we want to predict using the trained network, not another no-trained. So, use the same. :)

Comment: Many thanks.I modified like this(https://pasteboard.co/GK9wzm8.jpg ). Is it correct now?

Comment: Exactly, all right. And if you want to contrast results, compare variables 'forecastedLoad' and 'TT'.

Comment: I have used variables `forecastedLoad` and `targets2`.to plot actual and prediction results.Should i change `targets2` to `TT`?

Comment: No, no. Sorry, it is Ok. I did not saw the `targets2` variable. You are right, you should compare `forecastedLoad` and `targets2`. The `TT` variable is a NN data structure used for the network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154326/discussion-between-p-pronki-and-case-msee).

Comment: Thanks you very much for your comments and recommendations. :) 
I do not have Facebook but If you want to ask me any question, you can write me in the chat, because I do not check the e-mail regularly. But you can write me, I you want. I sent you a email.

Comment: I tried to find MAPE by mape = mean(abs(e./t)),but it gives NaN% in output as shown in ( https://pasteboard.co/GKpECK3.jpg )

Comment: Make sure that your input data and output data have not NaN values. However, if you want to ignore NaN values in the output, you can use [nanmean](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) usually if the Neural Network gives a NaN value is because the input is wrong.

Comment: Secondly, you didn't share you didn't share your email id?